# Redirect user to language other than default

Tags: i18n-l10n, redirection

So... i have set a drupal website with 2 languages, english (default) and portuguese. At some point during development the client asked me to change the default language to portuguese but as i've read all over the web that turning the default language to other than engish is not advisable. Is there a way to redirect the user to the portuguese version of the site?

Thank you all guys.
niebes

Comment: check https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect

Comment: I'm using a non-English language as default for a LONG time and seen not problem about it.

Comment: Hi Levox. I've turned the default language to portuguese but the menus aren't translated. Those menus are from taxonomy terms. Dunno why they are not translated tho... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer you're looking for:
[Install profile with variable default language messes up translations](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/install-profile-with-variable-default-language-messes-up-translations)

If the strings were originally written in english and not translated since you'll need to set the `i18n_string_source_language` variable to `en` rather than the site default (which is no longer `en`)